# C# pass repeated parameter to DataTable SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in my DataTable SQL Statement, now I confuse, how to pass date parameter to this query, the date is only 2, startdate and enddate, but the date is repeated several times.

```
SELECT        
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'E' OR
                                                         shift = 'F' OR
                                                         shift = 'G' OR
                                                         shift = 'H' OR
                                                         shift = 'J' OR
                                                         shift = 'P') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS P,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_8
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'N' OR
                                                         shift = 'O' OR
                                                         shift = 'S' OR
                                                         shift = 'T') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS S,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_7
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'B' OR
                                                         shift = 'M' OR
                                                         shift = 'Q') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS M,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_6
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'C') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS C,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_5
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'D') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS D,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_4
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'I') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS I,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_3
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'K') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS K,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_2
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'L') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) AS L,
                             (SELECT        COUNT(shift) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.JadwalKerja AS JadwalKerja_1
                               WHERE        (nip = dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan.NIP) AND (shift = 'R') AND (date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))) 
                         AS R
FROM            dbo.JadwalDinas_DaftarKaryawan
ORDER BY Nama
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare variables to hold those values as this:

```
DECLARE @sDate datetime, @eDate datetime

SET @sDate = '2015-12-01 00:00:00'
SET @eDate = '2015-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Then replace 
`CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)`
with
`@sDate`
and
`CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102)` with `@eDate`

You can create a stored procedure also containing all this query and reciving those variables as parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySP  @sDate datetime, @eDate datetime
AS
--Your query here
```